# How can i write string with html i made codebehind within a panal

Tags: asp.net

i have this string:

```
string foo = "<p>temp</p>";
```

how can i show it on my page
without using Response.Write(foo)

Comment: Where do you want to display it?  Is there already a control on the page that it should be added to, or do you need to add a container control somewhere on the page to display the message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to assign this value to the `Text` property of a [`Literal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol.aspx) control on the `.aspx`:

```
// in .aspx page:
<asp:literal runat="server" id="myText" />

//In the codebehind:
string foo = "<p>temp</p>";
myText.Text = foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Literal control, put Literal control on your page, and set

```
literal1.Text = foo;
```